# Organising folders in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a `terraform` setup in which i am creating resources in `aws`, i am using `s3`, `ec2` and also `kubernetes`. For `kubernetes` i have more than 5 `.tf` files. I have created a folder called `kube-aws` and placed the `.tf` files there. Right now i have a setup like below

```
scripts/
 |
  s3.tf
  ec2.tf
  kube-aws/
   | 
   web-deploy.tf
   web-service.tf
   app-deploy.tf
   app-service.tf
```

Is this a right approach, will `terraform` pick the `.tf` files from `kubw-aws` folder as well? or should i do anything else to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resources in `kube-aws` directory will **not be included** when `scripts` is your working directory. The `scripts` directory is considered the *root* module in this instance (see [Modules documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html)):

> The .tf files in your working directory when you run terraform plan or terraform apply together form the root module.

You have two options to include `kube-aws` resources:

1. Move them up to the `scripts` directory.
2. Create a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) block in one of the `scripts/*.tf` files and pass in required variables.

For example, in, say, `s3.tf`:

```hcl
module "kube_aws" {
  source = "./kube-aws"

  // pass in your variables here
}
```

The choice you make is entirely up to you but the guidance in [when to write a module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html#when-to-write-a-module) is pretty persuasive:

> We do not recommend writing modules that are just thin wrappers around single other resource types. If you have trouble finding a name for your module that isn't the same as the main resource type inside it, that may be a sign that your module is not creating any new abstraction and so the module is adding unnecessary complexity. Just use the resource type directly in the calling module instead.

I would recommend option 1 above, i.e. move your `.tf` files into a single directory, at least until you clear about when to use a module and how to best structure them. I would also highly recommend getting acquainted with the official (and excellent) documentation on [Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) and [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html), as well as looking at example modules in [Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/) and their associated source code (links to source can be found on module pages).